# Mysql sql error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near: `'SELECT count(*) FROM capacity 
>       WHERE
>        server=NEW.server
>       AND
>        feed'` at line 2

my code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS newsmonitoringrawdata.TNTInsertionTrigger;

CREATE TRIGGER TgtInsertionTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON tnews
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @isRecordCreated = 
 SELECT count(*) FROM capacity
 WHERE
 server=NEW.server
 AND
 feed=NEW.Feed 
 AND 
 date_Format(streamdt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')=date_Format(NEW.StreamDT,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');

 IF @isRecordCreated>0 THEN 
    UPDATE capacity 
    SET MsgNumber=MsgNumber+1, 
    size=size+NEW.MSize
    WHERE 
    server=NEW.server
    AND
     feed=NEW.feed
    and
     date_Format(streamdt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')=date_Format(NEW.StreamDT,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
 ELSE 
    INSERT INTO capacity(server, feed, streamdt, msgNumber, size) 
    VALUES
    (
        NEW.server,
        NEW.feed,
        date_Format(NEW.StreamDT,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'),
        1,
        NEW.size
    );  
 END IF; 

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @isRecordCreated = (
SELECT count(*) FROM capacity
WHERE
server=NEW.server
AND
feed=NEW.Feed 
AND 
date_Format(streamdt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')=date_Format(NEW.StreamDT,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
);
```

You have to add parantheses `()` around the query.